# Running AngularJS Protractor with proxy to https

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-e2e, protractor

I get the following error in the command line when trying to run Protractor:

> >
>   Fatal error: protractor exited with code: 1

I need to proxy to an https test server. How do I accomplish this? I followed the advice from this [Github issue](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/124), but I am still getting the above error. Here is my config file:

```
// A reference configuration file.
exports.config = {
   // ----- How to setup Selenium -----
   //
   // There are three ways to specify how to use Selenium. Specify one of the
   // following:
   //
   // 1. seleniumServerJar - to start Selenium Standalone locally.
   // 2. seleniumAddress - to connect to a Selenium server which is already
   //    running.
   // 3. sauceUser/sauceKey - to use remote Selenium servers via SauceLabs.

   // The location of the selenium standalone server .jar file.
   seleniumServerJar: './selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar',
   // The port to start the selenium server on, or null if the server should
   // find its own unused port.
   seleniumPort: null,
   // Chromedriver location is used to help the selenium standalone server
   // find chromedriver. This will be passed to the selenium jar as
   // the system property webdriver.chrome.driver. If null, selenium will
   // attempt to find chromedriver using PATH.
   chromeDriver: './selenium/chromedriver',
   // Additional command line options to pass to selenium. For example,
   // if you need to change the browser timeout, use
   // seleniumArgs: ['-browserTimeout=60'],
   seleniumArgs: [],

   // If sauceUser and sauceKey are specified, seleniumServerJar will be ignored.
   // The tests will be run remotely using SauceLabs.
   sauceUser: null,
   sauceKey: null,

   // ----- What tests to run -----
   //
   // Spec patterns are relative to the location of this config.
   specs: [
      './e2e/*-spec.js'
   ],

   // ----- Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance ----
   //
   // For a full list of available capabilities, see
   // https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities
   // and
   // https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/javascript/webdriver/capabilities.js
   capabilities: {
      'browserName': 'chrome',
      'proxy': {
         'proxyType': 'manual',
         'httpProxy': 'https://localhost.com:8443/'
      }
   },

   // A base URL for your application under test. Calls to protractor.get()
   // with relative paths will be prepended with this.
   baseUrl: 'http://localhost:9999',

   // Selector for the element housing the angular app - this defaults to
   // body, but is necessary if ng-app is on a descendant of <body>
   rootElement: 'body',

   // ----- Options to be passed to minijasminenode -----
   jasmineNodeOpts: {
      // onComplete will be called just before the driver quits.
      onComplete: null,
      // If true, display spec names.
      isVerbose: true,
      // If true, print colors to the terminal.
      showColors: true,
      // If true, include stack traces in failures.
      includeStackTrace: true,
      // Default time to wait in ms before a test fails.
      defaultTimeoutInterval: 10000
   }
};
```

Comment: More discussion here: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/124

Answer (score 6):

According to the [WebDriver capabilities documentation](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities#proxy-json-object), you should use 'hostname:port' as the format for the `httpProxy`. E.g.:

```
capabilities: {
  browserName: 'firefox',
  proxy: {
     proxyType: 'manual',
     httpProxy: 'localhost:8443',
     sslProxy: 'localhost:8888'
  }
}
```

Check your proxy software for the correct port.

This works in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for the response afternoon. I'll try out the localhost:8443 format.