# Protractor Proxy with Authentication

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am trying to setup proxy within `protractor` and utilizing authentication with the proxy. However, it doesn't appear to be taking when I add the username and password to the proxy url and port.

For example here is my `config.js` file (relevant section)

```
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    'proxy':{
        'proxyType': 'manual',
        'httpProxy': 'http://username:password@url:port',
        'sslProxy': 'https://username:password@url:port',
    },
    version: '47.0'
```

If I don't put in authentication it works just fine, but when I put the authentication stuff in there, it acts like there isn't a proxy at all and just bypasses it altogether.

Comment: Try putting your proxy values within quotes

Comment: I just mis-typed that, good catch, I have updated in the original question for future reference.  That doesn't work with quotes, just to be clear.

Comment: It should be in format hostname:port see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849417/running-angularjs-protractor-with-proxy-to-https

Comment: Yep, as I stated that does work, what, I am trying to do though is utilize authentication on my proxy, so that won't work, if I just do hostname:port, then I manually need to authenticate.  What I would like to do is just have it pass in the credentials and utilize them for every test without manual intervention.